# Expressing conditional probability in terms of cumulative distribution function of the normally distributed random variable epsilon

Tags: conditional-probability, cumulative-distribution-function

My objective is to derive an expression which lets me express the conditional probability of $A$ being less than 10 given that $B$ is equal to 20, in terms of the cumulative distribution function of $\epsilon$.

To do so, we're provided with the linear model in equation (1).

$$A = \beta_0 + \beta_1 B + \sigma\epsilon
\quad \quad \quad 
\epsilon \sim N(0, 1)
\quad \quad \quad (1)$$

And as far as I understand, I'd have to plug (1) into (2).  But after that, I'm completely at a loss and I have no idea how to proceed.

$$Pr(A < 10 | B = 20)
\quad \quad \quad (2)$$

Now, if someone could provide some help, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: what are $\beta_1,\beta_2$ ? Is $\sigma$ really $\sim N(0,1)$  or it's a typo?

Comment: I have taken the liberty of correcting the model equation to correct the error identified by @utobi.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $X \ \bot \ \epsilon$ (which is a usual assumption in regression modelling) you have:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(A \leqslant a | B=b)
&= \mathbb{P}(\beta_0 + \beta_1 B + \sigma \epsilon \leqslant a | B=b) \\[12pt]
&= \mathbb{P}(\beta_0 + \beta_1 b + \sigma \epsilon \leqslant a | B=b) \\[12pt]
&= \mathbb{P}(\beta_0 + \beta_1 b + \sigma \epsilon \leqslant a) \\[12pt]
&= \mathbb{P}(\sigma \epsilon \leqslant a - \beta_0 - \beta_1 b) \\[12pt]
&= \mathbb{P} \bigg( \epsilon \leqslant \frac{a - \beta_0 - \beta_1 b}{\sigma} \bigg) \\[6pt]
&= \Phi \bigg( \frac{a - \beta_0 - \beta_1 b}{\sigma} \bigg), \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

where $\Phi$ denotes the CDF of the standard normal distribution.